# CMake multiple version of fortran *.mod files

Tags: cmake, fortran

Fortran uses so-called mod files. They work similarly to a library. They are, however, important during compile stage of the objects. Now I am writing a CMake build for an older Fortran project. CMake luckily can recognise module dependencies. When CMake is compiling objects for a target they are stored in separed folder like:

> CMakeFiles/target_name.dir/src/

Mod files are not. Instead, they are stored in the compiler execution directory. In order to make compile and link stage work I add:

```
 target_include_directories( ${EXECUTABLE}
   PRIVATE
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
   )
```

So in the end *.o files are stored in separate directories and *.mod are in the build directory. This has worked well for me for some time. But now I have a project where it is not possible. I have multiple targets that are compiled out of the same source files using different precompiled options. There are no problems with *.o files because they are stored in separate directories. But if *.mod files are changed by these directives they cannot be stored in the same build directory.

I was thinking to move *.mod files into a separate directory after each compile stage and linking them with `${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/PRECOMPILER_OPTION_A`, but still I would have a problem with race conditions if I would use parallel make.

Is there a solution where I can specify the compiler execution path per target? Or are you aware of some other solution that would work?

Comment: Compilers often have options controlling where built module files are placed. If you were building "by hand", would you be using those options?

Comment: Yes, there is e.g. gfortran has -J option. I was thinking about it but then I would need to make this for each compiler which I would like to avoid. But if there is no better solution I have this trick in my sleeve.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fortran module files not found by CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917443/fortran-module-files-not-found-by-cmake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22898).

Basically the easiest solution is to manage `Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY` separatly for each target:

```
add_library(A OBJECT source.f90)
set_target_properties(A PROPERTIES Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/A)
target_include_directories(A PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/A)

add_library(B OBJECT source.f90)
set_target_properties(B PROPERTIES Fortran_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/B)
target_include_directories(B PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/B)
```